# Can't compile tryone144's branch of compton on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, compton

`make` command runs successfully with unused variables warnings however `make docs` returns the following error

```
a2x --format manpage man/compton.1.asciidoc
make: a2x: Command not found
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'man/compton.1' failed
make: *** [man/compton.1] Error 127
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `asciidoc-base` is missing. Install it by `sudo apt install asciidoc-base`.